# How to list all files from a specific directory using MediaStore?

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I am trying to list all the files from a specific folder but I can't understand how to do that using MediaStore. The code I have tried lists all the files from the internal storage, but I want to list all the files from a specific folder.

Here is my code:

```java
Uri collection;
final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
final String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?" +
    " OR " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?";
final String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
final String jpg = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("jpg");
final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
    mimeType,
    jpg
};
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
} else {
    collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
}
try (Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(collection, null, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)) {
    if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                @SuppressLint("Range") String columnData = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA));
                @SuppressLint("Range") String columnName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                @SuppressLint("Range") Long date = Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED)));
                ModalClass mediaFiles = new ModalClass();
                mediaFiles.setFileName(columnName);
                mediaFiles.setPath(columnData);
                mediaFiles.setDate(date);
                fileList.add(mediaFiles);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well first tell what is your specific folder?

Comment: "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents" this is my specific folder @blackapps

Comment: You posted an absolute path (starting with a /). That path does not exist on an Android device.

Comment: Does you code show the files from that folder now?

Comment: how could i define the path? for that specific folder, could you please show one example so that i can get some idea @blackapps

Comment: You posted your path wrong. Post the real path. And you did not tell if the files were listed now.

Comment: ok, so what i want to do is to get all pdf and images from whatsapp document folder,but what my code do is getting all the files from internal storage but i want only to  gets pdf and images from whatsapp document @blackapps

Comment: So you get those files listed now too? I asked that before and i dont see a clear answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251004/discussion-between-aisha-and-blackapps).

Comment: No chat. Please answer

Comment: @blackapps i don't think you can answer my question, and chat I had started because stack shows "the message Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Comment: I understand. But now please first answer my simple question. And im sure i can help with your question after you gave me the required info.

Comment: So you get those files listed now too? yes @blackapps

Comment: You should use column .RELATIVE_PATH as selection parameter and the relative path of the files as selection argument.

Comment: can you show me one example so that I could understand clearly  @blackapps

Comment: I will not do that as you added a `mediastore` tag. Click on it and read a couple of pages and you will see. Before you do that you could add to the code you already have such a column and print or log all relative path values. Then you know the value to select for.